# Sci-kit-learn Normalization removes column headers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a pandas data frame with 22 columns, where the index is datetime.

I am trying to normalize this data using the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Normalization
scaler = MinMaxScaler(copy = False)
normal_data = scaler.fit_transform(all_data2)
```

The problem is that I lose a lot of data by applying this function, for example, here is the before:

```
all_data2.head(n = 5)
Out[105]: 
                     btc_price  btc_change  btc_change_label  eth_price  \
time                                                                      
2017-09-02 21:54:00  4537.8338   -0.066307                 0    330.727   
2017-09-02 22:29:00  4577.6050   -0.056294                 0    337.804   
2017-09-02 23:04:00  4566.3600   -0.059716                 0    336.938   
2017-09-02 23:39:00  4590.0313   -0.056242                 0    342.929   
2017-09-03 00:14:00  4676.1925   -0.035857                 0    354.171   

                      block_size    difficulty  estimated_btc_sent  \
time                                                                 
2017-09-02 21:54:00  142521291.0  8.880000e+11        2.040000e+13   
2017-09-02 22:29:00  136524566.0  8.880000e+11        2.030000e+13   
2017-09-02 23:04:00  134845546.0  8.880000e+11        2.010000e+13   
2017-09-02 23:39:00  133910638.0  8.880000e+11        1.990000e+13   
2017-09-03 00:14:00  130678099.0  8.880000e+11        2.010000e+13   

                     estimated_transaction_volume_usd     hash_rate  \
time                                                                  
2017-09-02 21:54:00                       923315359.5  7.417412e+09   
2017-09-02 22:29:00                       918188066.9  7.152505e+09   
2017-09-02 23:04:00                       910440915.6  7.240807e+09   
2017-09-02 23:39:00                       901565929.9  7.284958e+09   
2017-09-03 00:14:00                       922422228.4  7.152505e+09   

                     miners_revenue_btc        ...         n_blocks_mined  \
time                                           ...                          
2017-09-02 21:54:00              2395.0        ...                  168.0   
2017-09-02 22:29:00              2317.0        ...                  162.0   
2017-09-02 23:04:00              2342.0        ...                  164.0   
2017-09-02 23:39:00              2352.0        ...                  165.0   
2017-09-03 00:14:00              2316.0        ...                  162.0   

                     n_blocks_total   n_btc_mined      n_tx  nextretarget  \
time                                                                        
2017-09-02 21:54:00        483207.0  2.100000e+11  241558.0      483839.0   
2017-09-02 22:29:00        483208.0  2.030000e+11  236661.0      483839.0   
2017-09-02 23:04:00        483216.0  2.050000e+11  238682.0      483839.0   
2017-09-02 23:39:00        483220.0  2.060000e+11  237159.0      483839.0   
2017-09-03 00:14:00        483223.0  2.030000e+11  237464.0      483839.0   

                     total_btc_sent  total_fees_btc      totalbtc  \
time                                                                
2017-09-02 21:54:00    1.620000e+14    2.959788e+10  1.650000e+15   
2017-09-02 22:29:00    1.600000e+14    2.920230e+10  1.650000e+15   
2017-09-02 23:04:00    1.600000e+14    2.923498e+10  1.650000e+15   
2017-09-02 23:39:00    1.580000e+14    2.899158e+10  1.650000e+15   
2017-09-03 00:14:00    1.580000e+14    2.917904e+10  1.650000e+15   

                     trade_volume_btc  trade_volume_usd  
time                                                     
2017-09-02 21:54:00         102451.92       463497284.7  
2017-09-02 22:29:00         102451.92       463497284.7  
2017-09-02 23:04:00         102451.92       463497284.7  
2017-09-02 23:39:00         102451.92       463497284.7  
2017-09-03 00:14:00          96216.78       440710136.1  

[5 rows x 22 columns]
```

Afterwards, I get a `numpy` array where the new index has been normalized (which is not good as it is the date column) and also all of the column headers are removed.

Can I somehow normalize only select columns of the original data frame while keeping them in-place?

If not, then how can I select only the desired columns froms the normalized numpy array and insert them back into the original df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`sklearn.preprocessing.scale`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html).  No need for the class-based scaler here.

> Standardize a dataset along any axis. Center to the mean and component
>   wise scale to unit variance.

You can use this like so:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : np.random.randn(10),
                   'col2' : np.arange(10, 30, 2),
                   'col3' : np.arange(10)},
                  index=pd.date_range('2017', periods=10))

# Specify columns to scale to N~(0,1)
to_scale = ['col2', 'col3']
df.loc[:, to_scale] = scale(df[to_scale])
print(df)
               col1     col2     col3
2017-01-01 -0.28292 -1.56670 -1.56670
2017-01-02 -1.55172 -1.21854 -1.21854
2017-01-03  0.51800 -0.87039 -0.87039
2017-01-04 -1.75596 -0.52223 -0.52223
2017-01-05  1.34857 -0.17408 -0.17408
2017-01-06  0.12600  0.17408  0.17408
2017-01-07  0.21887  0.52223  0.52223
2017-01-08  0.84924  0.87039  0.87039
2017-01-09  0.32555  1.21854  1.21854
2017-01-10  0.54095  1.56670  1.56670
```

To return a modified copy:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.loc[:, to_scale] = scale(df[to_scale])
```

As for the warning: hard to say without seeing your data, but it does look like you have some large values (7.417412e+09).  That warning is from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L164), and I would venture to say it's safe to ignore--it's being thrown because there's some tolerance test, testing whether your new mean is equal to 0, that's failing.  To see if it's actually failing, just use `new_df.mean()` and `new_df.std()` to check that your columns have been normalized to N~(0,1).

Comment: Well, your suggestion works with the following message `/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:160: UserWarning: Numerical issues were encountered when centering the data and might not be solved. Dataset may contain too large values. You may need to prescale your features.
  warnings.warn("Numerical issues were encountered "` but upon manual inspection of the data it looks like everything was scaled....is there not an interface between `pd` and `sklearn`?

Comment: How can I scale the selected columns in a manner that returns a copy of the original df instead of changing the values in-place? I may want to run each algorithm on the normal set and the scaled set to see what happens